# My bot pulls images from a local directory, how can I change this to a folder hosted on the web?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

I have followed a tutorial to produce a Twitter bot using node.js, github and Heroku.  Everything works great, the bot pulls a random image from a folder at timed intervals and tweets the image.

I'm trying to change the process so that instead of pulling images from a local folder (called 'images'), it pulls them from a web hosted folder. For example, rather than get the images from the local /images folder, I'd like it to pull the image from http://mysite/images.  I have tried changing what I think are the relevant bits of code below, but am having no luck. Could anybody offer some advice please?

The whole code is below, but for reference, the bits I have tried changing are:

```
var image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/images/' + 
    random_from_array(images))
```

and

```
fs.readdir(__dirname + '/images', function(err, files) {
```

In both cases above I tried changing the `/images` folder to http://mysite/images but it doesn't work. I get an error stating that no such folder can be found.  I have tried changing/deleting the `__dirname` part too but to no avail.

Any help appreciated!

Full code below:

```
const http = require('http');
const port=process.env.PORT || 3000
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.end('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
});
server.listen(port,() => {
console.log(`Server running at port `+port);
});


var Twit = require('twit')

var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    Twit = require('twit'),
    config = require(path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'));

var T = new Twit(config);

function random_from_array(images){
  return images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
}

function upload_random_image(images){
  console.log('Opening an image...');
  var image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/images/' + 
random_from_array(images)),
      b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, { encoding: 'base64' });

  console.log('Uploading an image...');

  T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, 
response) {
    if (err){
      console.log('ERROR:');
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log('Image uploaded!');
      console.log('Now tweeting it...');

      T.post('statuses/update', {
        /* You can include text with your image as well. */            
        // status: 'New picture!', 
        /* Or you can pick random text from an array. */            
        status: random_from_array([
          'New picture!',
          'Check this out!'
        ]),
        media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
      },
        function(err, data, response) {
          if (err){
            console.log('ERROR:');
            console.log(err);
          }
          else{
            console.log('Posted an image!');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
}


fs.readdir(__dirname + '/images', function(err, files) {
   if (err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else{
    var images = [];
    files.forEach(function(f) {
      images.push(f);
    });

  /*
    You have two options here. Either you will keep your bot running, and 
upload images using setInterval (see below; 10000 means '10 milliseconds', 
or 10 seconds), --
  */
    setInterval(function(){
      upload_random_image(images);
    }, 30000);

  /*
    Or you could use cron (code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks- 
   with-cron-jobs--net-8800), in which case you just need:
  */

    // upload_random_image(images);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, my first answer to a question about building a twitter bot would probably be: "Don't do that!"  (Because the world doesn't need more twitter bots.)  But, putting that aside...

Your code is using the "fs" library, which is exactly what you needed for grabbing stuff from the local file system.  That was fine.  But now you want to grab stuff from web servers, which "fs" is not going to be able to do.  Instead, you need a library that gives you the ability to make an HTTP or HTTPS request across the web and bring you back some data.  There are different libraries that do this.  Looks like you are already bringing in the "http" library, so I think you are on the right track there, but you seem to be using it to set up a server, and I don't think that's what you want.  Rather, you need to use http as a client, and replace your fs.readFileSync() calls with the appropriate calls from the http library (if that's the one you choose to use) to pull in the data you want from whatever server has the data.

Hope that helps.  And I hope your twitter bot is going to be a good little bot, not an evil one!

Comment: Thank you for the info.  Rest assured, this is purely for educational purposes,  No evil bots here :)

Comment: And the reason it's setting up the http server is purely to display a "Hello World" when the app is running (I was using this to make sure it was working) - kinda combined two tutorials into one.